# What to do when the OP changes a Question that has already been answered?

Tags: discussion

There is a [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20962/getting-error-pls-help) in the main forum that has been asked and answered. The OP then started adding comments asking other questions. I had asked the OP to create a new question rather than hi-jacking the original question. Instead of creating a new question the OP has modified their question to ask a new question, which makes the answers invalid now.

How should this type of change be handled?

Answer (score 3):

I flagged the question with the following info:

[image]